# Django makemigrations works, migrate fails with "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm stuck. Django 1.7, SQLite3.

I've changed my model to add the `thumbnail` column, as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b43JIn-OGZU). It was this:

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title
```

and is now this:

```
from django.db import models
from time import time         

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return  "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace(".", "_"), filename)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title
```

I backed up all data to a json text file with

```
python manage.py dumpdata article --indent=4 > article.json
```

and then executed

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

which worked. But

```
python manage.py migrate
```

fails with

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: article_article__new.thumbnail`

And now, even after adding `null=True` to the `thumbnail` line in `models.py`, running `makemigrations` succeeds, and `migrate` fails the same way.

What do I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My app name (as created with `python manage.py startapp`) is called `articles`. Here is the new `articles\migrations` folder, after getting the null-constraint error multiple times:

```
__init__.py
0001_initial.py
0002_auto_20140803_1540.py
0003_auto_20140803_1542.py
0004_auto_20140803_1450.py
0005_auto_20140803_1552.py
__pycache__
   __init__.cpython-34.pyc
   0001_initial.cpython-34.pyc
   0002_auto_20140803_1540.cpython-34.pyc
   0003_auto_20140803_1542.cpython-34.pyc
   0004_auto_20140803_1450.cpython-34.pyc
   0005_auto_20140803_1552.cpython-34.pyc
```

I deleted all the 000* files, in both directories, except 0001.

I then ran

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

successfully.

Thank goodness for `irc.freenode.net/django`.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is "Then don't do it and reroll back"

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another solution.

In my case how i created `BASE_DIR` was not correct hence  `DATABASES NAME` was also wrong. So it was creating the database at some other place. And when i was running migrations it was throwing this error propably because some old database existed there. So the fix was to just correct the `DATABASE` path.