# IntegrityError at * NOT NULL constraint failed: main_post.owner_id

Tags: django

I want to create a PostModel(just like instagram) and while the form is created to connect the user to the model with One-to-one/foreign key relationship, anyway I'm getting a problem while trying to upload an image and the db doesn't updates.

[I've tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109076/14792888)

```
...
# models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


...
# forms.py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('description', 'image', )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if commit:
            Post.save()
        return Post

...
# views.py
def account(request):
    post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if post.is_valid():
            post.save(commit=False)
            post.owner = request.user
            post.save(commit=True)
            messages.success(request, f"you had successfully updated your profile image")
            return redirect("main:account")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")

            return render(request = request,
                          template_name = "main/account.html",
                          context={'PostForm':post})

    post = PostForm()
    return render(request = request,
                  template_name = "main/account.html",
                  context={'PostForm':post})
```

[image]

Comment: Share your view.

Comment: just shared bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not override the `def save()` method, this is fine as it is now, so:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('description', 'image', )

    # no save
```

as for the view, you need to add the owner to the object, but here you are adding it to the *form*, and that thus has no effect (on the object):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def account(request):
    post = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.is_valid():
            post.instance.owner = request.user
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, f'you had successfully updated your profile image')
            return redirect('main:account')
    # …
```

I would also advise to rename `post` to `post_form`, since this is a *form*, not a post *object*.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: I am so appreciate your help! I have another issue now, the objects is fine but I can't actually display the image, <img src='{{post_form.image.path}}'> (I changed the way I'm named post as your adviced)

Comment: @yaronshamul: A form does not have an image. As said, there is a difference between the `PostForm`, which is a form that validates data, cleans it and can save it to the database and the `Post` *object*. You can render it for example, given that image exists with `{{ post_form.instance.image.url }}`. But you here will, in case of a *successful* POST make a redirect, so the page to which you redirect should render th eimage properly.

Comment: firstly thank you for the information, do you have any resource to lean this topics deeply? (instead of the doc, I will go there right after fix this issue) and if there are more cases that instances and forms can be confusing at? 
so I tried your solution above and it doesn't rendering well.. [html is here](https://pastebin.com/uy52XuyH)

Comment: @yaronshamul: how do you pass this to the template?

Comment: [link to the function](https://pastebin.com/wfrMs61L)

Comment: it seems that he can't read the instance after the post, I printed {{post_form.instance}} and got Post object (None), but the db is fine

Comment: @yaronshamul: but in case you submitted this to the form, and the form accepts it, you make a `return redirect('main:account')`. That view (to which the `account` goes), should fetch the related `Post`s (there can be multiple), and thus render it properly. This is thus *not* the view that submits the image. In the new view, you thus can fetch the posts with `posts = Post.objects.filter(owner=request.user)`, and then in the template render this for example with `{% for post in posts %}{{ post.image.url }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226307/discussion-between-yaron-shamul-and-willem-van-onsem).